# SQL Server connection string for big concurrent connection

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection

I've been searched this page : [SqlConnection.ConnectionString Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx)

But, I am not really sure the property that I should use. So far, I used `Max Pool Size` and `Pooling` property.

I build REST API will be used by more than thousand user per minutes. I got bad result in insert query process (POST request). There are data not successfully inserted to the table. How can SQL Server handle this problem? At least from connection string property. Tell me if connection string can't help too.

**Update**: my connection string:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
     connectionString="Server={my_server},1433;Database={my_db};User ID={my_user};Password={my_password};Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;Max Pool Size=1000;Pooling=true;" />
```

Comment: `ConnectionString` is totally unrealted to any pooling, concurency and so on. It is just string with some connection settings: server address, database name, authentication type etc. So it' unclear - what your question exactly is.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev:  `Max Pool Size` and `Pooling` are really part of the connection string. Read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx @OP: Can you show the connection-string that you are using? Have you noticed any problems?

Comment: @TimSchmelter oh, missed it because never was needed to set it in connection string. Anyway, it doesn't make question somehow clearer, I think.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev, I did insert process and the result not really good for big concurrent connection (race condition probably).

Comment: @andrefadila: what kind of race condition? How is this related to the pooling- and poolsize issue? Can you show the code/sql where you expect a race condition? In general it depends on the kind of queries and the code if the default pool-size of 100 is sufficient for 1000 parallel users.

Comment: I am not really sure about this. I am using autonumber for primary key. Is it related?
If it's sufficient, how about more user? How do you count? Sorry, too much questions.

Comment: It sounds to me as if you are trying to insert many rows at once and are having poor performance.  Have you looked at the `SqlBulkCopy` class?

Comment: Exactly @ChrisDunaway, actually I don't know this question is related with `SqlBulkCopy`. I have browsed `SqlBulkCopy` but have not implemented it yet. Do you have any recommendation?

Answer (score -1):

You can add the `Max Pool Size` property in connection string.

```
string constring = "server=yourServer;database=yourDatabase;uid=id;pwd=password;Max Pool Size=200;"
```

Comment: Yes, OP has already mentioned it. But that doesn't answer a question which is still not clear.